# Razor Pages accessing list items using Html.DisplayFor vs property directly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Rendering a list of objects into `HTML` in Razor Pages I found two options.
Are these the same?

Using model property directly

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ResumeList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DeviceID</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

vs using `Html.DisplayFor`

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ResumeList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeviceID)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

If not, what is the functional advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DisplayFor helper renders the corresponding display template for the given type.If you don't add custom format,the results of `Html.DisplayFor` and property directly will be the same.

If you add custom format,`Html.DisplayFor`,it will respect the custom format,and property directly will not.Here is a demo:

```
public class Test {
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

view:

```
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SomeProperty)
</div>
<div>
    @Model.SomeProperty
</div>
```

result:

[image]